# How to manage Azure EventGrid Authorization Scheme?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, authorization, azure-eventgrid

I'm trying to post an Event in C#, but getting an error regarding the authorization scheme.

I'm executing the code in a webjob in an app service in Azure.
This is the code giving me problems:

```
Using Microsoft.Azure.EventGrid;

var eventGridClient = new EventGridClient(credentials);
client.PublishEventsAsync(topicHostname, events).Wait();
```

The error I get is this:

> Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Request has an unsupported
> Authorization scheme:Bearer. Authorization scheme must be
> SharedAccessSignature.

Where can I manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message, you are using the wrong credential, it should be the code like below.

```
string topicEndpoint = "https://<topic-name>.<region>-1.eventgrid.azure.net/api/events";
string topicKey = "<topic-key>";
string topicHostname = new Uri(topicEndpoint).Host;

TopicCredentials topicCredentials = new TopicCredentials(topicKey);
EventGridClient client = new EventGridClient(topicCredentials);
client.PublishEventsAsync(topicHostname, events).Wait();
```

Reference - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/eventgrid#publish-events

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was using AzureCredentials, and switching it to TopicCredentials I got it to work.